# Recyclerview is not getting updated in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm trying to create a recycler by adding items per item, I already did by creating with a already existent list and it worked fine, but not by adding item per item. This is how I'm doing.

Fragment :

```
layoutManager =  LinearLayoutManager(context);
recyclerView?.layoutManager = layoutManager;
recyclerView?.adapter = SubCategoryAdapter();


 builder.setView(dialogLayout)
        builder.setPositiveButton("Salvar") { _, _ ->
           var model: SubCategoryModel = SubCategoryModel(alertTitleEdit.text.toString(),alertDescriptionEdit.text.toString(),null);
            adapter.run{
                addItems(model)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
        builder.show()
```

Adapter

```
class SubCategoryAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<SubCategoryAdapter.SubCategoryHolder>() {

private var dataM: List<SubCategoryModel> = mutableListOf();

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SubCategoryHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_sub_category, parent, false)
    return SubCategoryHolder(view);
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return dataM.count();
}

fun addItems(model: SubCategoryModel){
    dataM.toMutableList().add(model);
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SubCategoryHolder, position: Int) {
    var res = dataM[position];
    holder.title.text = res.Title;
    holder.description.text = res.Description

}

class SubCategoryHolder (val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    lateinit var title: TextView;
    lateinit var description: TextView;
    lateinit var price: TextView;
    var v: View = view;
    init {
        title = v.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        description = v.findViewById(R.id.description);
        price = v.findViewById(R.id.price);
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, nothing happens.

Comment: Hope the answer solved your issue

Answer (score 1):

```
private var dataM: List<SubCategoryModel> = mutableListOf();
```

The problem is with the type `List` it's not mutable.

In here `dataM.toMutableList().add(model);` the `toMutableList()`.

The method does this

```
public fun <T> Collection<T>.toMutableList(): MutableList<T> {
    return ArrayList(this)
}
```

It returns a completely new instance, not the instance you have in your adapter.

You can do this

```
private var dataM: ArrayList<SubCategoryModel> = ArrayList();
```

and for adding item

```
fun addItems(model: SubCategoryModel){
    dataM.add(model);
    notifyItemInserted(dataM.count()-1);
}
```

Comment: @NathielPaulino what issue you are facing?

Comment: the list is not showing! I debugged and the dataM is filled but after that the layout is not inflating, as if it was missing to update the thread or something, I don't know, it only works if I pass a existent list through the adapter constructor, but adding one item at the time doesn't !

Comment: what is the current code in this `fun addItems(model: SubCategoryModel)`?

Comment: `dataM.add(model)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare variable like this and use it

```
var adapter:SubCategoryAdapter()?=null
```

Then initialise it

```
layoutManager =  LinearLayoutManager(context)
recyclerView?.layoutManager = layoutManager
adapter = SubCategoryAdapter()
recyclerView?.adapter = adapter
```

Comment: The adapter and inside of setPositiveButton is right ?